# Hyperledger Fabric transaction payload visible in ordering node

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to know if transaction payload in Hyperledger Fabric transaction flow is visible to the ordering nodes.

The goal is to create a private channel, where only the owners of the peers have the possibility to see the payloads and therefore what is saved in the ledger, while we would like to increase the decentralization of the network by distributing the orderer nodes to multiple organization, but it is important that these orderer nodes never know the transaction payload and what is saved on the blockchain.

In my opinion is something possible but I would like to be sure because is a crucial point of the architecture's design.

Answer (score 0):

Orderers do see the data recorded in the ledger by a transaction. If it really isn't practical to have orderers owned by the same set of organisations that own network peers, you might be able to use private data collections:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html

Data stored in private collections is shared directly between peers with permission to view that collection, and only a hash of the data is stored in the main ledger and visible to orderers.